# html to excel dont work with very many rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

Good day,

I have a functionality on my report that converts html tables into an excel file. its working fine to tables with 1,500 rows, but with more than it. It doesnt work. I am currently using a js plugin called [table2excel](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel) and its not generating any error as well.. could it be a memory issue or some sort? thanks for the tips.. I am trying to export a log-table, and naturally it will generate very many rows as time passes..

code:

```
<div class="box" id="dataTable">       
   <?php $excel_title = "GENERAL LEDGER"; $col_no = 9; ?>
   <table class="table table-bordered report-table" >
     <thead>
        <th width="10%"  >Account</th>
        <th width="4%">Date</th>
        <th width="5%"   >Trans #</th>
        <th width="20%" >Description</th>
        <th width="9%"  class="ar" >Ref #.</th>
        <th width="9%"  class="ar" >Debit</th>
        <th width="9%"  class="ar" >Credit</th>
        <th width="9%"  class="ar">Amount</th>
        <th width="9%"  class="ar" >Balance</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>    
       <tr>
       <th>value#</th>
       <th>value#</th>
       <th>value#</th>
       <th>value#</th>
       <th>value#</th>
       <th>value#</th>
       <th>value#</th>
       <th>value#</th>
       <th>value#</th>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

$('#table2xcel').click(function(){
  $("#dataTable").table2excel({
    exclude: ".xpage",
    name: "Worksheet Name",
    filename: "{{$excel_title}} -"  //do not include extension
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
            window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
            e.preventDefault();
        });
 });  
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" />
    <div id="dvData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row1 Col1</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 Col1</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 Col1</td>
            <td>row3 Col2</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```